# Keras validation and loss fluctuation overfitting

Tags: r, keras

I developed a deep learning model, and I was wondering why my validation loss and validation accurary is fluctuating. Is it a sign of overfitting? I tried to play with hyper-parameters like dropout and learning rate. I have 7 inputs and 2 outputs. Size of training data is about 57381.

```
model7 <- keras_model_sequential()
model7 %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 8,
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.001),
              activation = "relu",
              input_shape = c(7)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 22,
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.001),
              activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 2,
              activation = "softmax")
summary(model7)

# Compiling the model
model7 %>% compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
                   optimizer = "adam",
                   metrics = c("accuracy"))

history <- model7 %>% 
  fit(x_train,
      y_train,
      epoch = 200,
      batch_size = 64,
      validation_split = 0.2)
```

[image: Keras model history]

Can you tell me if I am overfitting, and if you can give some advices to modify my model?

Comment: Try decreasing the learning rate of the optimizer or changing optimizer.

Comment: I would like to know if validation accruacy is over accrucy, and loss over val_loss, is that good ?

Comment: Your validation loss and accuracy are not over your training values, but they are oscillating around the training values, indicating maybe some degree of instability but not overfitting.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried with learning rate = 1e-6 with the same fluctuation. The degree of instability is due to what? It can be corrected?

Comment: Hard to tell, it could be any number of things: noisy data, bad train/validation split, batch size, ... All in all the model does not look bad.

Comment: I changed batch_size=1000, and after 180 epoch it looks less fluactions